# Как вывести последние 2-е буквы из каждого слова массива? C++

Tags: c++, строки, stl, vector

У меня имеется массив из 5 слов. Я нахожу в этих словах нужные мне буквы и меняю их. А вторая задача состоит в том, что необходимо взять по 2-е последние буквы из каждого слова, и вывести их в подстроку. Т.е. берем слово **maybe** и из него надо взять буквы **be**, после чего вывести их на экран.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void myfunction(string& i)
{
    for (auto idx = i.find("ab"); idx != string::npos; idx = i.find("ab"))
    {
        i.replace(idx, 2, "ccc");
    }
}
int main()
{
    vector<string> v;

    v.push_back("soon able brabus strong crab");
    ostream_iterator<string> printit(cout, " ");

    cout << "Before replacing" << endl;
    copy(v.begin(), v.end(), printit);

    for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), myfunction);

    cout << endl;

    cout << "After replacing" << endl;
    copy(v.begin(), v.end(), printit);
    cout << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Я нашел как просто удалить слова с определенными буквами, нашел как искать слова с неповторяющимися буквами. Но как найти 2-е последние буквы в словах массив, а потом вывести их на экран, я не смог.

Comment: Я думал, у Вас проблема именно со строкой, а не с векторами. Дополнил свой ответ, посмотрите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужно вытаскивать из массива слов то так наверно:

```
std::vector<std::string> temp;

for(auto& it:v){

temp.push_back(it.substr(it.size() - 2, 2));
}
```

Затем вывод этого массива строк "с последними 2 буквами":

```
for(auto& it:temp){

cout << it<< "\n";//printf_s("%s", it.c_str())
}
```

Comment: Теперь он выводит только последние 2 символа последнего слова. Что если поставить запятые, и ориентир был на них? Возможно тогда он выведет все последние 2-е буквы слов. Но как это сделать?

Answer (score 3):

[`string::substr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) Вам в помощь:

```
string source = "maybe";
string result = source.substr(source.size() - 2, 2);
cout << result << "\n";
// output: be
```

**UPD.** С вектором:

```
// вектор исходных слов
vector<string> words;
words.push_back("maybe");
words.push_back("go");
words.push_back("to be");
words.push_back("banana");
// вектор для окончаний
vector<string> ends;

// добавление окончаний слов
for (auto it = words.begin(); it != words.end(); it++) {
    string &s = *it;
    // можно добавить ещё проверку на достаточную длину слова
    ends.push_back(s.substr(s.size() - 2, 2));
}

// вывод
for (auto it = ends.begin(); it != ends.end(); it++) {
    cout << *it << " ";
}
cout << "\n";

// output: be go be na
```